# No login prompt on tty[1-6] on Ubuntu 12.04.05

Tags: linux, login, console, tty

After disabling X on startup, no login ttys are offered on the console.

I don't see any login prompt in any of the tty[1-6], just a line saying "* Starting Automounter       [OK]"

I have all the getty processes running and if I kill one, it respawn correctly.

```
root      1662     1  0 Sep28 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root      1668     1  0 Sep28 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root      1684     1  0 Sep28 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root      1685     1  0 Sep28 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root      1688     1  0 Sep28 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root     11278     1  0 Sep29 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Any clue? TIA

Comment: The kernel was loaded with:

 ro nomodeset pcie_aspm=off quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Comment: @Segio: as the author your can always edit your own questions to update them with additional details/corrections/improvements instead of commenting.

Answer (score 1):

When you deactivated your X server at startup, did you remember to add `nomodeset` to the proper GRUB line? In `/etc/default/grub` edit this line to look like

```
        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

then run `update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

You system video drivers somehow messed up.

Try to give `nomodeset` parameter by editing grub during boot and see if that helps.