# Ubuntu Server 16.04 tty console is out of bounds

Tags: ubuntu, boot, console, tty

After booting there are leftovers of boot logs in the console. It is always a fixed number of lines. 
In console mode with the resolution of 640*480 it covers the whole screen leaving the console prompt completely out of bounds and I'm forced to use it blindly.

In graphics mode it covers only a little top section of the screen divided from the operational part of the screen by a purple line, however when the console becomes filled with text the prompt still goes out of bounds, so I'm still forced to operate half blind.

[image: Console as seen in graphics mode]

Comment: Your monitor is probably too old to send EDID data to the computer which would tell it the correct screen resolution. Replace the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/726846/no-login-prompt-on-tty1-6-on-ubuntu-12-04-05?rq=1).
The problem was in the grub settings. I've just set the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Thanks, everyone who tried to help me!